# R - subsetting data.frame in combinationar manner

Tags: r

I've data.frame like below:

```
Name Feature
A    1
B    2
C    4 
D    1
E    7 
F    5
G    2
H    2
```

I have to create from this data series of data.frames with three rows in commbinationar manner. In another words, I need to obtain

subsetted_data.frame_1

```
Name Feature
A    1
B    2
C    4
```

subsetted_data.frame_2

```
Name Feature
D    1
G    2
H    2
```

subsetted_data.frame_3

```
Name Feature
F    5
G    2
H    2
```

And so on - to finally create all possible combinations. I was tried to use split function (from data.table package), but it doesn't work. Whis is the easiest way to obtain  this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subset data.table based on all possible combinations of two or more variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508342/subset-data-table-based-on-all-possible-combinations-of-two-or-more-variables)

Comment: what pattern are you using to make your subsetted data frames? #1 and #3 make sense but #2 confuses me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combn` to get a matrix of indexes and then pass them as the argument to a `lapply` anonymous function.

```
cmb <- combn(nrow(dat), 3)

sub_data <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(cmb)), function(i) dat[cmb[, i], ])
names(sub_data) <- sprintf("subsetted_data.frame_%02d", seq_along(sub_data))
```

**EDIT.**

Following @AkselA's comment I have tried his code and, if run before setting the `names` like the code above does, the two results are the same in the sense of `identical`, meaning, they are exactly the same.

```
sub_data2 <- apply(cmb, 2, function(x) dat[x,])
identical(sub_data, sub_data2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**DATA** in `dput` format.

```
dat <-
structure(list(Name = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), Feature = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Name", "Feature"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Not quite worth a separate answer, but a slightly more concise alternative to your `lapply()` line is: `sub_data <- apply(cmb, 2, function(x) dat[x,])`.

Comment: @AkselA Thanks, I have edited the answer with your code.